# How to insert JSON into Apache Ignite Cache on the fly (without Java class) using Binary Builder?

Tags: java, json, caching, ignite

I am proficient in Python but beginner in Java and since Python is not supported - looking for a working example-code in Java or NodeJS (not [Documentation](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/binary-marshaller#modifying-binary-objects-using-binaryobjectbuilder) which has snippets and partial code) about how to store JSON into Apache Ignite cache and then query any field (with field query).

Problem is that JSON can have different structure every time (one time can have 3 fields, next time 30 fields), all controlled by user.

Is there any working example showing the whole process from beginning (JSON from some file) to the end (Ignite cache)?

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there is a full example for this. You need to do the following:

- Choose a JSON parser to use in your application (most likely it would be GSON or Jackson, others are much less popular).
- Figure out how to fully traverse a JSON object using this parser (refer to their documentation for this).
- While traversing, update `BinaryObjectBuilder` (basically, call `setField` for each field in JSON object). Ignite binary objects allow to have dynamic schema, so it's OK if one object has 3 fields and another 30 fields, even if they are of the same type.
- When finished, call `build()` and put resulting `BinaryObject` into cache.

Comment: Great, thanks for direction! How will this process scale if there are 100,000 JSON objects per second (or more)? Messages will come from Kafka topics and wondering - where would this logic above (java code once is built) sit? (on client side or nodes of Ignite cluster somehow)

Comment: You can do both actually, but generally I suggest to do this on clients. This way you will be able to scale Kafka consumers and actual server cluster separately. But note that this will likely require more machines.

Comment: Is it possible for JSON to be multi-dimensional? (e.g. Array of Array of Array with Key -> Values in each level). Not sure how Ignite would support multi-level JSON object (so far I've seen only examples with 1 dimension-level array). Thanks.

Comment: This is possible, `BinaryObject` can have a field which is another `BinaryObject` or even a collection of `BinaryObject`s. However, keep in mind that you will not be able to index and query the data that is inside the collections.

Comment: Ok so for first level fields - we can set indexes and query fields but if is BinaryObject inside of another BinaryObject then that second level-deep fields are not accessible via SQL query? Is there some work-around for this? Maybe created a second cache for 2nd-level deep fields and another cache for 3rd level deep fields? Or would it be better to use instead of Ignite - some other document-store (e.g. Cassandra or MongoDB) in order to achieve and work better for nested structure in order to access or query fields that are at the last (e.g. 4th) level?

Comment: Ideally, you should create separate data model for Ignite. Ignite is designed for more relational like models where different data types are stores in different tables with foreign key references. For example, if your JSON represents an `Organization` with multiple `Employees`, you should create a separate objects for organization itself and each employee, and then do multiple updates.